# Loop a function over speaker list

Tags: r

I do have a problem concerning a function-build. I try to accomplish the following:

I do have a dataset `df` which contains a couple of variables, and amongst other things a text vector. This text vector should be cleaned (stemming, delete stop-words,...), processed through a supervised classification-algorithm and the result (`readme.results$est.CSMF[[2]]`) stored.

The function wasn't that hard to script, but what makes a big headache is the repetition of this function. I want to repeat/loop this list over a unique speaker list and over different points of time.

```
df_select <- df[df$date >= "1990-12-20" & df$date <= "1994-11-10",]


liste = list()

for(i in 1:)
{
  df_select <- subset(df_select, df_select$speaker == paste(speaker_list[i]))
  {
  complete_fun <- function(){

    df_sample <- sample_n(df_select , 200, replace = T)


    df_sample$text <- as.character(df_sample$text)

    df_sample$text <- tolower(df_sample$text)
    df_sample$text <- tm::removeNumbers(df_sample$text)
    df_sample$text <- tm::removePunctuation(df_sample$text)
    df_sample$text <- str_replace_all(df_sample$text, "  ", "")


    df_sample$text <- tm::removeWords(x = df_sample$text, stopwords(kind = "german"))

    setwd("~/test")

    fn1 <- function(N) {                                                             
      for(i in 1:length(N)) {                                                              
        file.out <- paste("data", i, ".txt", sep = "")                           
        write.table(N[i], file.out)                                              
      }                                                                            
    }    

    fn1(df_sample$text)




    #### README - Classification Algorithm ####

    undergrad.results = undergrad(sep = ";", ignore.case=T, stem=T)
    undergrad.preprocess <- preprocess(undergrad.results)
    readme.results <- readme(undergrad.preprocess,n.subset=300)
    readme.results$est.CSMF[[2]]


  }
  liste[[length(liste)+1]] = readme.results$est.CSMF[[2]]  
  }
  df_select <- df
}
```

Comment: 1) `for(i in 1:)` is not R, you are missing the end point of the vector `1:`. 2) Do not *define* the function in the loop, define it somewhere else. In the loop you should *call*  the function. 3) Function `sample_n` comes from an external package, you should start your posted scripts with instructions to load those packages, `library(dplyr)`, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your data I have no opportunity to test this, but something like this would be a better approach.

Define the functions by themselves.

```
setwd("~/test")

fn1 <- function(N) {                                                             
  for(i in 1:length(N)) {                                                              
    file.out <- paste("data", i, ".txt", sep = "")                           
    write.table(N[i], file.out)                                              
  }                                                                            
}    

complete_fun <- function(x){

  df_sample <- sample_n(x, 200, replace = T)


  df_sample$text <- as.character(df_sample$text)

  df_sample$text <- tolower(df_sample$text)
  df_sample$text <- tm::removeNumbers(df_sample$text)
  df_sample$text <- tm::removePunctuation(df_sample$text)
  df_sample$text <- str_replace_all(df_sample$text, "  ", "")


  df_sample$text <- tm::removeWords(x = df_sample$text, stopwords(kind = "german"))

  fn1(df_sample$text)


  #### README - Classification Algorithm ####

  undergrad.results = undergrad(sep = ";", ignore.case=T, stem=T)
  undergrad.preprocess <- preprocess(undergrad.results)
  readme.results <- readme(undergrad.preprocess,n.subset=300)
  readme.results$est.CSMF[[2]]

}
```

Then we can create a loop that use this function and stores its output in a list

```
df_select <- df[df$date >= "1990-12-20" & df$date <= "1994-11-10",]

liste = list()

for (i in 1:length(speaker_list))
{
  df_select <- subset(df_select, df_select$speaker == paste(speaker_list[i]))
  liste[[i]] <-  complete_fun(df_select)

  #not necessary
  # df_select <- df
}
```